# Problem with storing 10 integers into an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok, I'm very confused as to why this happens. All I'm trying to do is put 10 integers from input into an array. Why is this happening.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getData(float intArray[10]);

void printData(float intArray[10]);



int main() {
float myArray[10];
getData(myArray);
printData(myArray);

cin.get();
cin.ignore();


}

int getData(float intArray[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                  
    {                                                        
        std::cout << "Enter a number:";
        std::cin >> intArray[10];
    }
    return 1;
}

void printData(float intArray[10]){

    cout << intArray;

    }
```

If you could please tell me where I'm going wrong, that would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention, the output is just random integers and characters. EX: 00B3F724

Comment: You're not reading into an array, you're reading into element `[10]` of the array - which doesn't exist and gives you undefined behavior. Printing the contents of array elements that haven't been set isn't good either.

Comment: My goal is to enlighten you. If that means telling you what you did wrong, that's what I'm going to do. If that means solving some quirky corner of the programming universe, that's what I'll do instead. It's all down to the quality of the question.

Comment: `std::cin >> intArray[10]`  reads an `int` and writes it to one past the last element of `intArray`.   That is undefined behaviour.   Fix it by changing `intArray[10]` to `intArray[i]` so the loop reads values sequentially.   The statement `cout << intArray;` outputs, as a pointer, the address of the first element of that array.  Pointers  (other than pointers to `char`, which are treated differently) are conventionally output in a hex format.   Fix that by creating a loop that, each time around the loop outputs one element of `intArray`. Voting to close as both problems are essentially typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in this block of code-

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                  
    {                                                        
        std::cout << "Enter a number:";
        std::cin >> intArray[10];
    }
```

As mentioned in other answers and comments you are storing all the values in the 10th memory slot of the array.

As per your comment

> I forgot to mention, the output is just random integers and characters. EX: 00B3F724

**00B3F724**=> These are the memory address allocated to the array and which will hold the elements which will be inserted.

How array actually works-

```
float myArray[10];
```

The above snip creates 10 units of memory space. The units differ on the type which the array will hold. In this case it is holding float values, so each memory space will be of 4 bytes. All of these spaces have an address for lookup and other operations. All these spaces are expecting a float value to be inserted.

As you are using the loop you have to loop through the array(all the memory slots allocated to the array) and allocate a float element to each one of them and not only the last element(10th).
Effectively your for loop will become

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                  
        {                                                        
            std::cout << "Enter a number:";
            std::cin >> intArray[i];
        }
```

Instead of `intArray[10]` insert values like this `intArray[i]`. As i will traverse through all the slots on every iteration of the loop insert a values to a slot.

Your code will look like

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int getData(float intArray[10]);
void printData(float intArray[10]);
int main() {
float myArray[10];
getData(myArray);
printData(myArray);
cin.get();
cin.ignore();


}

int getData(float intArray[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                  
    {                                                        
        std::cout << "Enter a number:";
        std::cin >> intArray[i];
    }
    return 1;
}

void printData(float intArray[10]){

    cout << intArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

From how your code is written, you're only adding the user's input to the `[10]` element of `intArray[]` within that `for` loop you created. Additionally, any information added to the array at `intArray[10]` or beyond is placed out of bounds.

The only way I can really demonstrate what I mean is...

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout<<"Enter a number:";
    std::cin >> intArray[i];
}
```

Another thing I noticed is you're creating another array with the same name in your `printData` method. You should instead pass the `intArray` you're filling up with information to this method and use it to display your information.

Answer (score 0):

As you know if an array is declared as myArray[10], its index ranges from 0-9. Putting a value in myArray[10] will go out of bound and will produce garbage value.

In getData(float intArray[]) you are always overwriting the content of intArray[10] while it is out of bound so it is not being stored in an actual array. You should write your  getData(float intArray[]) as following :

```
int getData(float intArray[]) {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)                                  
{                                                        
    std::cin >> intArray[i];
}
return 1;
}
```

Also in printData(float intArray[10]) you are only printing the base address of the array (i.e the name of the array gives the address of the 0th index).So the correct code would be:

```
 void printData(float intArray[])
{
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
  cout << intArray[i]<<" ";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change,

```
std::cin >> intArray[10];
```

to,

```
std::cin >> intArray[i];
```

**What you are doing wrong:**

you are storing the value at the 10th position (actually it is 11th position) again and again and the value at 10th position replaces with the new value again and also the 10th position doesn't exist in the array because the index of the array starts from 0, so your array has the index values from 0 to 9.